# Fix <div> to middle of viewport in pure Javascript w/ 'position: absolute'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to fix a `<div>` to the middle of the screen using pure JavaScript without using `position: fixed` due to other app design constraints.

---

**Attempts to Fix Include:**

**JS**:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.getElementById('hide-side').style.top='-'+((document.body.scrollTop)*-10)+"%";
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div className="side">
  <div id="side" >some container</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
 #side {
   position: absolute;
   right: 100%;
   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   display: inline-block;
   opacity: 1;
 }`
```

Comment: why don't you want to use position fixed?

Comment: May I ask why a javascript solution? Because scroll events are performance hogs

Comment: because im doing another things to that div that cant be handled with fixed so i need it to be abstract

Comment: Would you consider `position: sticky;`?

Comment: @Mike i want it to be absolute with a javascript handler if that's possible

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute the scroll position and position it absolutely.

This in production is quite hard to get it right, since you have to take into account viewport zoom, and other stuff, like when your "modal" is not directly attached to the body, you will have to compute its offset against the document and position it accordingly.

```js
document.body.onscroll=function(e){
  modal.style.top = `${window.scrollY}px`;
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 2000px;
  background: url(https://www.designyourway.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Seamless-Space-Pattern-by-J.jpg);
}

#modal{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  Modal
</div>
```

Comment: my problem is i cant do that compute

Answer (score 1):

I know you have asked for a javascript solution but I just wanted to bring to your attention that what I think you want to achieve can be done with pure html, css.

I have created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f0b5myzr/5/ where this line:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

does all the hard work for you.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

## Pure JS :

[image]

```js
window.addEventListener("onresize", me);

me();

function me() {
    const div = document.getElementById("center");
    div.style.left = (window.innerWidth - div.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
    div.style.top = (window.innerHeight - div.offsetHeight) / 2 + "px";
}
```

```css
#center {
position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">center</div>

<div id="middle"></div>
```

Comment: You could also use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Values_in_JavaScript) set in your Javascript to save reference to the `top` + `left` values and use those in your CSS